# Tkinter "intervention" in a logic loop

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm not sure the title describes my issue in a comprehensive manner.

I have made a working "loop" code in Python (even with working recursive functions) for some sort of a card game "AI". See the following pseudo-code:

```
def move():
    if Turn == "Computer":
        if Computer cannot play:
            return False
        else:
            Do some "AI" stuff... the computer plays
            Turn = "Player"
            move()
    elif Turn == "Player":
        if Player cannot play:
            return False:
        else:
            in = input("Select Card: ")
            ****So here the loop stops and waits for the input from the player
            ...then the input is evaluated and "played" as a player move
            Turn = "Computer"
            move()
    

while continue:
    continue = move()
```

So if the computer can play, it plays the card, the turn changes to Player and the move function is called again, otherwise false is returned and the PC-Player back and forth turn is over. In the Player's turn the loop stops to wait for the user input from terminal and then it continues...
So far everything works, but now I want to implement a GUI for player input. I have some basic knowledge with Tkinter and so far I created buttons on screen rapresenting the player's cards. The question is how can I "stop" the loop waiting for the user to click a button (corresponding to the card - or the PASS TURN). Maybe with some sort of threading but sounds complicated... there must be an easier solution like in the "Terminal input version" that I have already working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a loop in a GUI, because the GUI has it's own loop that needs to run. The `mainloop()` in tkinter. You need to shift your planning to "event driven" programming. It sounds like in your case the event would be the user choosing a card.

```
def player_chooses_card():
    # graphic and logic updates for player's choice

    # computer turn
        if Computer cannot play:
            trigger graphic for end of game
        else:
            Do some "AI" stuff... the computer plays

    # function is done; back to idle state waiting for an event
```

FWIW making a loop with recursion is bad style in python.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain on the Tkinter loops. It was a hard lesson for me to learn as well. Loops such as while and for DO NOT WORK in tkinter. The way I typically solve this problem is with "root.after." Take the code in your loop and define it as a command (adding root.after(1, name of your command) like so:

```
def myloop():
    move()
    root.after(1, myloop)
```

Then, call it for the first time right before 'root.mainloop', like so:

```
<your other code>
root.after(1, myloop)
root.mainloop()
```

Also keep in mind that Tkinter does not make nice nice with multiprocessing/threading within mainloops, so you have to set up each process/thread as its own canvas and root.

Finally, you could set up a series of if statements and variables to separate your loop into chunks so that it stops and starts based on player input. For example,

```
def myloop():
  if playerhasdonething == True:
     move()
  else:
     print("waiting on player")
  root.after(1, my mainloop)
```

I apologize if I missed the point of your question, this is how I personally would try to solve your problem